# .Batch file does not like variable for php executable

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which is going to be called by Windows Task Scheduler to execute given .php file.

However there seems to be a problem because when I provide full path to php.exe i.e.

```
start /B /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f %inputTask% >> %outputDir%
```

batch file executes as it should, but when I try to give variable like so:

```
set php="C:\xampp\php"
start /B /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f %inputTask% >> %outputDir%
```

if fails given the following error :

> Windows cannot find '-f'. Make sure you type the name correctly, and
>   then try again.

Comment: `start /B /wait "C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f %inputTask%" >> %outputDir%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Start` command considers the first double-quoted parameter to be a window title...

[`START`: Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

> Syntax
>
> ```
>   START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
> ```
>
> Always include a `TITLE` this can be a simple string like `"My Script"`
>   or just a pair of empty quotes `""`.  According to the Microsoft
>   documentation, the title is *optional*, but depending on the other
>   options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Comment: Yes that has solved the problem :) -  adding empty quotes was sufficient